# Define a unique and global assembly label/symbol inside C functions

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I want to mark specific C lines with sort of assembler label/symbol which will not occupy any space in the binary but by examining the linker output map file I will know all occurrences of such generated labels and, eventually, of the C code that was "marked" this way. So I want to be able to define such labels, and to make them global, and **used** so the linker does not throw it away
I also need some macros magic to have those labels have a unique name each time the C code is preprocessed ( to make sure each inlined instance of the function has its own label - otherwise I will have duplicate symbols, I guess )

Example :

```
// my build system will pass -DMYFILE_ID for each file, here I am trying to create a unique literal for each inline instance of the function
#define UN(X) #X
#define UNIQUE(X,Y) UN(X##Y)

void my_func(void)
{
    _asm("GLOBAL_LABEL_"UNIQUE(MYFILE_ID,__LINE__)":\n\t")
    my_c_code_I_want_to_track();
}
```

And what I would like to have at the end, is in the linker output symbols map file, something like that

```
0xsome_address GLOBAL_LABEL_12_1
0xdifferent_address GLOBAL_LABEL_12_2
0xyeanotheraddress GLOBAL_LABEL_13_1
```

which basically should give me an idea at which addresses my_c_code_i_want_to_track got instantiated

The whole idea is sort of inspired by how the labels in assembly are actually "symbols" that have a placement and so their addresses can be checked but they dont actually occupy its own space.

Problems :
1. Is it even possible to have assembly labels be defined like that
2. How to make those labels stay and appear in the output symbols map file
3. Something is wrong with the UNIQUE macro as I get "label redefined" when trying to compile

Comment: And your problem is what exactly?

Comment: question edited with problems definitions

Comment: Not sure how inlining works, it may very well reuse the same `__LINE__`. As for your map file: how do you create that?

Comment: map file - it is output by the linker, not sure which argument triggers that. But what I want to know is how actually to make compiler create an actual symbol for that label and the linker to actually treat it as something "needed" and not just to throw it away as not referenced ..

Comment: Globals should not be thrown away, referenced or not, unless you explicitly request that.

Comment: I do ask linker to optimise those away. But since this fellow is not expected to occupy any space in the binary, I am looking for a way to "reference" it, some sort of "__attribute((used))" over it, to tell the linker I want to include it ..

Comment: It would probably be simpler to extract the address information before stripping the binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that you may get multiple copies of the same label due to inlining. Add the following attribute to functions containing these labels:

```
__attribute__((noinline))
```

Also note that you need to mark the symbol as global. Let's extract this into a macro so we can format nicely without changing the value of `__LINE__`:

```
#define MAKE_LABEL \
    __asm__( \
        "GLOBAL_LABEL_" UNIQUE(MYFILE_ID, __LINE__) ":" \
        "\n\t.global GLOBAL_LABEL_" UNIQUE(MYFILE_ID, __LINE__) \
    )
```

But the macro-expansion is off. Unfortunately, I cannot explain to you why this works. But here is the correct macro definition:

```
#define UN(X) #X
#define UNIQUE2(X,Y) UN(X##Y)
#define UNIQUE(X,Y) UNIQUE2(X,Y)
```

Otherwise you will get `__LINE__` instead of, say, 23.

Comment: GNU C Basic `asm` (no operands) is implicitly `volatile`.  So is Extended `asm` with no output operands.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I was unaware of this.

Comment: Any idea how to also add something like __attribute((used)) for that, so even if the linker is asked to throw away any unreferenced symbols - those labels stay ?

Comment: @LouisShraga: What linker options are you specifically using that is causing this?

Comment: Not sure about the linker optimisation flags as this is how I got the build system. The thing is, I dont want to change it since the project is very scarce in memory. So I am just looking for a way to dummy-reference those labels

Comment: @LouisShraga: You're going to have to tell us more about the built toolchain. The way `__attribute__((used))` works is different on different systems.

Comment: @LouisShraga: Note that if your build system includes a call to `strip`, which is not exactly uncommon, you might just want to start there. You can do things like extract the symbol information into a separate file. It depends on the build system and toolchain.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `%=` (e.g. `label%=:`) inside an [Extended-`asm` template](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) to get the compiler to generate a unique number to avoid name collisions when a function containing inline-asm is inlined multiple times in one compilation unit.

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define STR(x) STRINGIFY(x)
int foo(int x) {
    asm("marker" __FILE__ "_line" STR(__LINE__)  "_uniqueid%=:" :::);
    return x+1;
}


int caller1(int x) {
    return foo(x);
}

int caller2(int x) {
    return foo(x);
}
```

compiles to the following asm with `gcc -O3` ([on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23define+STRINGIFY(x)+%23x%0A%23define+STR(x)+STRINGIFY(x)%0Aint+foo(int+x)+%7B%0A++++asm(%22marker%22+__FILE__+%22_line%22+STR(__LINE__)++%22_uniqueid%25%3D:%22+:::)%3B%0A++++return+x%2B1%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aint+caller1(int+x)+%7B%0A++++return+foo(x)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+caller2(int+x)+%7B%0A++++return+foo(x)+%2B+2%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:51.99203187250996,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:48.007968127490045,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+8.2',t:'0')),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:48.007968127490045,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)):

```
foo(int):
        marker/tmp/compiler-explorer-compiler11899-55-1ki0cth.pehm/example.cpp_line4_uniqueid7:
        lea     eax, [rdi+1]
        ret
caller1(int):
        marker/tmp/compiler-explorer-compiler11899-55-1ki0cth.pehm/example.cpp_line4_uniqueid22:
        lea     eax, [rdi+1]
        ret
caller2(int):
        marker/tmp/compiler-explorer-compiler11899-55-1ki0cth.pehm/example.cpp_line4_uniqueid41:
        lea     eax, [rdi+3]
        ret
```

This of course won't assemble because `/` isn't a valid label character in GAS.

Using `MYFILE_ID` which contains only characters that can appear in symbol names, this would assemble just fine, and you should be able to see all the `marker` labels in `nm` output.